# Trigger banner notification when user if logoff in window

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, cmd, shutdown

is that possible to trigger window banner notification when user is logoff from the PC? In Shutdown.exe when running this command:

```
shutdown.exe /r /t 30 /c "Hi this pc is shutting down, Please save you work!"
```

The notification banner can be display, but it seems `/c` does not work with `/l`. Is there any alternative for me to display the notification banner during log off? my plan is to let the window auto log off using `Process.Start()` in c# when any user tend to change my config, but before log off i need to warns the user with notification banner, and all process i will run as a window service. Your help much appreciated.

Comment: Cannot be achieved using just shutdown.exe since you cannot use the logout option (/l) with the timeout option (/t) ```/l - Logs off the current user immediately, with no time-out period. You cannot use /l with /m or /t.``` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown
Alternative is to do it yourself: MessageBox.Show your message and start a Timer or similar to run `shutdown.exe /l`

Comment: Hi @Wh1t3rabbit, Thanks for the response. Yes , i planned to use Messagebox, but i executed my script using window service where messagebox unable to interact with the GUI.

Comment: Ah ok, I see how that is an issue. There is a lot of results out there for 'messagebox from windows service'. If you can't get that working you might want to ask it as a separate specific question.